# LoadRunner 12 does not record Siebel HI 8.1 + IE11 script

Tags: testing, performance-testing, loadrunner

When I start to record a script with LR12 + IE11 for Siebel HI 8.1 version, I'm getting the error:

[image]

But it does not happen when I access manually it - I can access it normally.

Anyway, I can record a Siebel OpenUI 8.1 script with LR12 + IE11.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the user access control to low and try it.

if not go for load runner 12.5 and we are able to record siebel application in IE 11 and Vugen 12.5

Comment: Where can I find free version of LR 12.5? In HP page I only see LR 12.02 free version.

Comment: goto hp passport wesite and search it you will get it.

Comment: if not contact HP with your SAID they will help you.